# PHP number between an interval depending on input string

Tags: php, string, intervals

**In php I can do this:**

```
echo rand(5, 15);
```

It will give me a number between 5 and 15, different every time.

**Static number depending on input string**

```
echo my_static_number(5, 15, 'some/custom_string');
```

I still want a number between 5 to 15. The difference is that I want it to be calculated depending on the third argument, a string.

- Allowed output numbers 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
- The same number every time as long as the function call stays the same.

**Real life example**

Images in a folder:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
etc.
```

Php call:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_image(1, 15, $url); ?>">
<img src="<?php echo get_image(1, 15, $url); ?>">
```

Output something like this:

```
<img src="7.jpg">
<img src="7.jpg">
```

Same number every time as long as the function call is the same.

Comment: You can call `rand()` function and then save returned number with unique identificator (for ex. your `$url`) and then, before another `rand()` call, you can check, if for this rand is already exist number.

Comment: Should this work on a general basis or just per one execution of the script?

Comment: @Yoshi It should not generate different results on different execution. The same result if the function call with arguments are the same.

Comment: @JensTörnell I think you're looking for some kind of hash function. Why don't you use that instead?

Comment: @silkfire Instead of what? But yes, great answers have come in and they are hash based. :)

Comment: @JensTörnell Read on what a hash function is. It transforms a value and will give you the same result every time for the same string.

Comment: @silkfire I know what a hash is. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that you are building load balancer.

What you need here is to calculate a [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) from the string and tranform that to number. A good pseudo-random hash-function will be sufficient to get you a random distribution. One solution might be like this:

```
function my_static_number($a, $b, $str) {
    $hash = hash('crc32', $str); // crc32 is probably the fastest here
    $dec = hexdec($hash); // convert hash to a decimal value
    $base = $b + 1 - $a; // +1 is needed to include $b as possible value
    return $a + fmod($dec, $base); // get remainder from $dec / $base
}
```

Some tests on [teh playground](http://www.tehplayground.com/#mwT0G1lB9):

Update: There may be slight improvement in speed if you take first 2 chars of the `$hash` instead and then use `$dec % $base` instead of [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php):

```
function my_static_number($a, $b, $str) {
    $hash = substr(hash('crc32', $str), 0, 2); // effectively produces a number between 0 and 255
    $dec = hexdec($hash);
    $base = $b + 1 - $a;
    return $a + $dec % $base;
}
```

I did a test on random distribution and both functions do [reasonably well](http://www.tehplayground.com/#Zd9wje9di).

Comment: Tried it. Works great! Any pitfalls at all?

Comment: I think it can have some speed improvement if you take only first 2 chars of the `$hash` and then you can use integer-based remainder: `$dec % $base` instead of `fmod`. That should be a tiny bit faster. As for the randomness - in theory it should be random, but I didn't performed proper tests.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I thought of when I read your question:

```
function my_static_number($min,$max,$seedStr)
{
  $hash   = md5($seedStr);
  $length = strlen($hash);
  $seed   = 1234;
  for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) $seed += ord($hash[$i]);
  srand($seed);
  return rand($min,$max);
}


echo my_static_number(5, 15, 'some/custom_strings');
```

`rand()` can be seeded, and with the same seed it will generate the same random sequence. So I hash the complete string, add up the ascii values of that hash, and use this as a seed.

So you will get random numbers, but they will be the same for the same seed strings.

This function does have some limits:

- speed: It's not the fastest. If that's needed you need a completely different algorithm.
- randomness: There is slight decline in randomness of the output due to the limited number of seed values. This can be improved.

Thinking about it: There's no real need to use any random function here: You can use the hash to compute a semi-random number. Like so:

```
function my_static_number($min,$max,$seedStr)
{
  $hash   = md5($seedStr);
  $length = strlen($hash);
  $number = 1234;
  for ($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) $number += ord($hash[$i]);
  return $min + ($number % ($max-$min));
}

echo my_static_number(5, 15, 'some/custom_string');
```

Comment: You can use [crc32](http://www.php.net/crc32) to produce integer hash from string.

Comment: It works! Great! If you have the time and want to you could try the hash compute thing. UPDATE: Other solutions coming in, will try them as well.

Comment: Well, I got somewhere, didn't I? :-)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware So far I think the Ruslan version is really hard to beat.

Comment: @Jens Törnell: Yes, the trick to use crc32's hex result and convert it to decimal is quite nice. The basic idea is the same though.